# How to change the color of the bottom line underneath a SearchView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-view, searchview

Pretty straight-forward, how do I change the color of the line along the bottom of a SearchView in Android? I've tried, queryBackground, background, and various other things but cant seem to get it in XML. Im happy doing it programmatically or in XML. Just want it to work!

Cheers[image: SearchView example]

Comment: did you try setting accent color?

Comment: @Shane Monks O'Byrne have tried with my answer.

Comment: Hi chetan , I'm out of the country at the moment, I will be trying your solution later this week - thank you very much for your answer. I'll mark as answer if it's correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Below method to change colour of bottom line of SearchView.

Here I add Blue Colour as bottom Line

```
private void customizeSearchView() {
        int searchTextId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
        EditText searchBox = ((EditText) searchView.findViewById(searchTextId));
        searchBox.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        searchBox.getLayoutParams().height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        int search_plateId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_plate", null, null);
        View mSearchPlate = ((View) searchView.findViewById(search_plateId));
        mSearchPlate.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

        int searchCloseImageId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_close_btn", null, null);
        ImageView searchClose = ((ImageView) searchView.findViewById(searchCloseImageId));// change color
        searchClose.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
```

Comment: This is the answer, thanks. Worth noting that you need to fill the EditText with a background color also (like you have here), otherwise the entire searchview turns the color of the searchplate.

Answer (score 0):

hi try this it may help you

```
  android.support.v7.widget.SearchView searchView=findViewById(R.id.search_view);
    View v = searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_plate);
    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("color code"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView searchView = findViewById(R.id.Search_Categorie);
View v = searchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_plate);
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```